# CSS file reverts back to unmodified version when project is built using Viusal Studio 2019

Tags: css, asp.net, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

My ASP.NET project has a CSS file which initially had 2 classes before I took over

```css
.ClassA
{
    background-color: red;
}
.ClassB
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Now I needed to add another class to my CSS file supposedly named as .ClassC, so I added that:

```css
.ClassA
{
    background-color: red;
}
.ClassB
{
    background-color: green;
}
.ClassC
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But as soon as I built the project, the file came back to its original state:

```css
.ClassA
{
    background-color: red;
}
.ClassB
{
    background-color: green;
}
```

I am unable to figure out whats going on here. Either it has to do something with the github or the all new Visual studio 2019.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated. If the answer is going to provide a detailed view of how visual studio deals with different files(in the background) while building a project, that will be an icing on the top.

Comment: It could be a cache problem on your browser or your app. Try to add a dumb querystring in your css file request. somtihing like: "~/yourfile.css?v=2" this will force the browser and the server to send you the newest version of the file.

Comment: Hi @LuttiCoelho The question is not how the CSS file is behaving in browser, but its about how it is being treated in IDE, our own beloved visual studio. "How the latest changes made in the CSS get reflected in browser" has grabbed a lot of geeky attention, but nothing found on this one. Seems like an issue with Visual studio.

Comment: Sorry, but I think I didn't understand your problem yet. After you change your css file, the file "rollback" inside visual studio?

Comment: Yes exactly that's what I am saying, I am not running the project (it will take me to a browser). I am just building it. The file is open right in front of me while I am building it and it just rolls itself back as soon as the Output pane says build succeeded.

Comment: Are you using bower, npm, nuget or anything to manage frontend libs?

Comment: I am using nuget, but this file is not being managed by nuget. its a project specific locally defined css file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224210/discussion-between-asad-jamil-and-lutti-coelho).

Comment: @AsadJamil, based on my test, I can not reproduce your problem. However, I have two suggestions. First, I advise that you can create a new css file to check if it works for you. Second, you can put the css content in your style. Like this [Example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_howto_internal).

Comment: Hi @JackJJun-MSFT thanks for taking out ur precious time. Of course we can add css in the content but that is not our desired behavior.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I make changes/build. It reverts the changes to previous code. I've cleared cache cookies everything. It's almost like the builds and gets overwritten by the .min file or something.